# Facebook Login with JS SDK and PHP SDK. Is it safe to pass access_token in form?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, sdk

I am doing a login with facebook on my website.
Unlike most logins I see....my users may already be signed up and later want to connect to their facebook.  If they jump the gun and click 'login with facebook' when they already have an account on the website, they may end up creating a new account...which we don't want.

Instead, I have it set up so they login with facebook...and upon returning, check to see if the fbID or the fb email exists in the current db.  If not...then present them with a login screen to login normally.  At that time they will connect the two accounts. I have been researching for this quite some time and I am very surprised I don't see this method posted everywhere on the web.  Seems logical to me.

To be clear, I use the FB JS SDK, to do the login with facebook popup.  Then after the redirect, I use the FB PHP SDK to obtain the fb user ID and the users info from facebook.

Ok...so...one issue I have been having, is that after logging in with facebook...and then getting redirected back to a normal login screen, the facebook authentication is GONE when submitting normally. In order to finish connecting the two accounts in a secure manner, I would like to authenticate the user a second time before updating the database with their facebook ID.

In an effort to do this....I have decided to obtain the fb access_token with the first login, and then populate the normal login with the access_token.  Then upon submitting normally, I can use the access_token to gain the user info with the php sdk and store the fb ID in my db.

However, is this safe?  Passing the access_token in a form?   Also...I noticed there was a way to obtain the "code" key, and use that to later obtain the access_token and the user_info.  However, I am not sure how to obtain the "code" when using the fb JS sdk login.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.  I hope I was clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should never transfer the access_token between client and server. When somebody gets hold if it, they can perform actions for the user under your Apps name.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "the facebook authentication is GONE when submitting normally".

Have you read the guides on using Authentication with the PHP SDK? You can find them here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0#authentication

Using the `FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper` you can easily get the information from the logged-in user, using JS, to your servers.

For the JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.1#login

Comment: Thx for the reply. I have read these. Trouble is I need to obtain the variables in php so I use the php sdk after the js login. Next, after you refresh the page a second time, as I mention, the php sdk no longer obtains the variables. $user an $user_info are now empty. If I can't pass the access_token, is there a way I can a) obtain the 'code' variable from fb js sdk, and then pass that on the refresh?  Would that be more safe?  I beleive I can use the code var along with app secret and app ID to obtain the access_token if I am not mistaken.  Thank you